# How to apply condition for specific page in magento?

Tags: magento, url, conditional-statements

I want to apply condition for specific page coming from url. It is neither a category page nor a custom cms page. Url is like localhost/project/index.php/news/blog.html. I want to apply condition for this 'news/blog.html' . News or blog is not a category and not any cms page. Can anybody help me?

Comment: where is the file placed "blog.html" in setup? Give project demo link.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of condition, you want to user over there. You can try with the following.
1. Try to put a observer in the relevant controller using the cheat sheet https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-5/
2. Directly try to edit model in the module of that page.
3. Try to put some code directly into the file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
```

It will give controller name to your module. Put consition for this name and write your code. It will work for sure.